# What is the effect of temperature changes on rate of chemisorption?

Tags: surface-chemistry

In chemisorption, if temperature increases, then after some time why does its rate decrease? I tried to explain it by Le Chatelier's principle but I don't believe it's valid as chemisorption is irreversible, so there won't be any equilibrium.

I also wonder what effect would the decrease of the temperature have on chemisorption. Going by the above pattern I believe it should be the reverse but I am not sure.

Comment: If the surface is of finite extent, when full no more molecules can be adsorbed. In the simplest (Langmuir) model, the rate of adsorption is proportional to the fraction of the surface that is empty.